# How does 'auto purchase items' work in dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

There's an option in settings that toggles *auto purchase items* on and off.

How does it work?
Does it automatically buy the next item in my selected build when I have the gold? Does it buy whatever it wants? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It automatically buys items when you can afford it using a list of items for your hero.

Because it does not have strict order I would recommend against using it. Better to set up the quick buy key ?

Comment: I made a script for this, I used F1 as the trigger to see my hero. `bind "F1" "+dota_camera_follow; dota_purchase_quickbuy"` Now, F1 will open the shop and also show my hero.